# Phone Authentication with React Native on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I'm integrating Firebase phone authentication in my ReactNative app. I followed the steps mentioned in [Firebase Phone Authentication](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth)

Its working good in iOS. After entering password its showing verification screen as in attached image.
[image: Verification Screen]

In Android, I crosschecked the package ID, I included the SHA key generated. But its not showing verification screen. No error or no message as well.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: have you configured your apn key with firebase ?

Comment: @aryanagarwal oh, I didn't see info about setting up APN key with firebase. can you point me to right tutorial to set it up.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried on a physical device?

In Android, It will not show the verification screen.

Comment: Yes, its working on the physical device and not in emulator.